# Issue with a Cordova Android app using WebRTC camera

Tags: android, cordova, webrtc, android-webview

I'm working on an Cordova Android app. Recently, I've added the vue-qrcode-reader which uses device camera via WebRTC API.

I build the app in the debug mode which produces a file called `app-debug.apk`.

Since I've added this feature, I've began to face several problems.

1. The app never asks for camera permission when needed. Instead, users have to manually toggle camera permission on in the Android App Manager. Every install it automatically reverts to toggled off.
2. Users unable to update the app via the .apk file. It always fails with the "**App not installed**" error. Users have to manually remove the app from the device and install it. Before adding the camera feature this error didn't happen and it always updated the app.
3. Even if I have both parameters `android:allowBackup="true"` and `android:fullBackupContent="true"` set to enabled, every app install it always starts "clean". I use WebView localStorage API. Again, before adding the camera feature updating or removing the app would keep the storage data intact.

My user permission section in the generated **AndroidManifest.xml** looks like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
```

Update: added `cordova plugin list` output and `config.xml` contents.

**cordova plugin list**

```
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-keyboard 1.2.0 "Keyboard"
cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.3 "LocalNotification"
cordova-plugin-qrscanner 3.0.1 "QRScanner"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine 1.2.1 "Cordova WKWebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr 2.1.1 "Cordova WKWebView File XHR Plugin"
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification 0.8.2dev "LocalNotification"
```

**config.xml**

```
<content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <!--<plugin spec="https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git#b8f358e" />-->
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>

    <allow-navigation href="*" />

    <platform name="android">
      <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
      <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
      <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
      <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
      <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000"/>
      <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-hdpi/screen.png" />
      <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-mdpi/screen.png" />
      <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-xhdpi/screen.png" />
      <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-xxhdpi/screen.png" />
      <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-xxxhdpi/screen.png" />
      <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-hdpi/screen.png" />
      <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-mdpi/screen.png" />
      <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-xhdpi/screen.png" />
      <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-xxhdpi/screen.png" />
      <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-xxxhdpi/screen.png" />
      <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/mipmap-ldpi/ic_launcher.png" />
      <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icon/android/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
      <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icon/android/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
      <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icon/android/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
      <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/icon/android/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
      <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="res/icon/android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    </platform>

    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="local" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0" />
    <preference name="Suppresses3DTouchGesture" value="true" />
    <preference name="Allow3DTouchLinkPreview" value="false" />
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
```

Comment: You need to paste your config.xml / plugin list

Comment: @Eric added to my post